# How to implement Configurations class in Java?

Tags: java, configuration-files

I am using this [example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/quick_start.html) to read from configuration file (data such as host name, password, etc) . But they did not include the Configurations class itself.

So I am not really sure how that should be implemented.

Here is how I am trying to read the properties from Main class:

```
Configurations configs = new Configurations(); // Error: cannot find symbol symbol: class Configurations location: class Main
try {
    Configuration config = configs.properties(new File("database.properties"));
    String dbHost = config.getString("database.host");
    int dbPort = config.getInt("database.port");
    String dbUser = config.getString("database.user");
    String dbPassword = config.getString("database.password", "secret");  // provide a default
    long dbTimeout = config.getLong("database.timeout");
} catch (ConfigurationException cex) {
    cex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is how my database.properties file looks:

```
database.host = "dbname";
datatabase.port = 5005;
datatabase.user = "root";
datatabase.password = "";
database.timeout = 60000
```

P.S. Sorry for my stupidity, I am very new to Java.

Comment: are you using @Configuration annotation on top of your main application class

Comment: The Configurations class is this one - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/builder/fluent/Configurations.html and they do include it.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani no I am not using that

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev I saw that, its not the class code itself, just an explanation. I could not set it up by myself.

Comment: You don't need to see the Configurations class code. Its documentation says everything you need to know. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Also, this may sound like a nit-pick, but using the correct terminology can help you get the right answers by helping readers understand your question. You're not implementing the Configurations class yourself. The Apache Commons project has already implemented it. You're just trying to _use_ it.

Comment: @k314159 how about I NEED THE CLASS CODE. I believe that's clear enough.

Comment: It's at https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration

Comment: If you mean you need to _include_ the class into your classpath, then it depends, if you're using Maven or Gradle, you can get the dependency at https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2/2.7/jar . If you're not using a build tool, you can download the jar file from the Apache Commons website.

Comment: @k314159 cmon man dont send me the entire github repo link, just point it out. I am totally lost.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/configuration2/builder/fluent/Configurations.java

Comment: But if you just want to _use_ the class, then see my earlier github repo main page, and scroll down to the section titled "Where can I get the latest release?"

Comment: @k314159 so if I only copy-paste that class it should work with the rest of my code? do I need to make any changes to it?

Comment: No, you can't just copy-paste that class into your code, because that class uses all the other classes from that repo. You need the whole jar file. See my later reply and follow the section titled "Where can I get the latest release?"

Comment: @k314159 would it be possible to minimize it to only use the code I need? I basically need to read from the properties file. And that Properties file should be editable as well. That's it.

Comment: In that case, you don't really need the Configurations class, as that sounds like overkill. You can use the Properties class which is part of the Java API, and not a 3rd-party library. If you really want to use Configurations, you might get away with editing the class source code and removing things that you don't need. But that sounds complicated. It might be easier to persevere with trying to use just the Properties class directly, as in the answer below (maybe with some tweak).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties class in java, which has a load method that specifies an inputstream.
Then, you can read your properties file via FileInputStream.

example：

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        InputStream inputStream =
                new FileInputStream("D:\\work_space\\java_workspace\\test-mq\\src\\main\\resources\\database.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);

        String host = properties.getProperty("database.host");
        // get more properties......
        System.out.println(host);

    }

}
```

Comment: The above is the implementation method without any framework, it only needs the most basic java environment.

Comment: Fails with error: "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project NettySimpleTCPServer: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]"

Comment: I can't answer you would based on your information, if you can, you can provide more misinformation so I can judge better.

Comment: alright sir, I will upload the entire project now to this post so you can get more info

Comment: @showtime this guy has given you a good answer. The error message that you replied with has no relation to this answer. That error message simply says that your program failed to run. You can't expect anyone to be able to do anything with something as generic as that. You should look at the cause of the failure and paste the relevant error message, which should have been shown somewhere in your output before the "execution failed" message. Anyway, as I said, this answer looks good to me. Maybe you just need to change the directory name or the name of the property